# NServiceBus Multicast Publish-Subscribe Channel with RabbitMQ Transport

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, messaging, publish-subscribe

**Tech Stack**:

- .Net 4.6.1
- Erlang 18.3
- Language:  C# 6
- NServiceBus 6
- RabbitMQ 3.6.3
- Windows 7

**Context**:
We are trying to implement a dumb event publisher with smart subscription in NServiceBus on the RabbitMQ transport.

1. All interested receivers subscribe to an event.
2. A Publisher publishes the event to an event channel.
3. All subscribers receive a copy of the event.
4. Note that I did not say each TYPE of subscriber receives a copy of the message.  If there are multiple instances of a service running, and they all have active subscriptions to an event, each INSTANCE of the subscribing service should get a copy of the message.

However, NServiceBus' notion of Publish-Subscribe delivers a published event to one and only one receiver on a given channel.  In our case, one instance of a given subscribed service.

I hesitate to list messaging "patterns" because they don't seem to be named or described particularly consistently.  However, I believe we are esentially trying to implement the "Multicast" version of the Publish-Subscribe Channel messaging pattern from the Enterprise Integration Patterns (Hohpe and Woolf) Book.

**Problem Statement**:
Our business case is this:

1. We have a configuration service that provides application configuration to all other services in our broader application.
2. Each service requests its configuration from the configuration service on startup by sending a *ConfigurationRequest* message.
3. The configuration services replies to the specific instance that made the *ConfigurationRequest* with a *ConfigurationResponse*.  This is done using NServiceBus' Full-Duplex (commonly called Request-Response) feature.
4. There is a website that can modify configuration globally.  When it does so, it notifies the configuration service with an *UpdateConfiguration* command.
5. The configuration service publishes a *ConfigurationUpdated* event that all other services are subscribed to.
6. Each service can have multiple instances running on more than one server.  ALL instances of a service need to update their configuration, not just one instance.
7. Each service instance is calling NServiceBus' EndpointConfiguration.MakeInstanceUniquelyIdentifiable with a distinct discriminator.
8. Currently when we publish the *ConfigurationUpdated* event, only one instance of each service type gets the message.  The events are distributed round-robin, instead of each instance getting a copy of the message.

We have worked around this problem by keeping a record of running services instances and sending the *ConfigurationUpdated* event (as a Command in NServiceBus) to each of them individually, but Pub-Sub implies that we should have dumb publishers and smart subscribers, and our workaround is the opposite...  Our publisher looks up a listof each subscriber and sends to it implicitly.  Is there some configuration I am missing on the subscriber side that would allow each instance of each service to get a copy of the published *ConfigurationUpdated* event?  If not, where should I look in NServiceBus to start implementing such a feature?  Routing topology, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not familiar enough with nservicebus to know how to do it with that toolset, but the RabbitMQ implementation would be a "fanout" exchange with a queue per consumer.

Every queue bound to a fanout exchange will get a copy of the message. If there is a single consumer for each of those queues, then you will be sending a copy of the message to each of the consumers.

It sounds like you have multiple consumers connected to the same queue. Maybe there's a way to tell nservicebus to create a queue for each consumer instance?

---

p.s. you're right about pub-sub pattern being multicast. i talk about this in my RMQ Patterns ebook (https://leanpub.com/rmq-patterns) and that's what the EIP book would say, as well.

Comment: The reply we got back from Particular was that they intentionally don't support this behavior.  I can't understand why.  They don't want you to "message all the things."  They think an event, generally, should have one publisher.

They suggested we use Redis for our application, which is probably the right answer.  However, our leads don't want to support the infrastructure at this time, so we built a Multicast Message Proxy that sends commands to each recipient.  Ugly, but it works very reliably.  Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @EricBurcham I have the same issue as you. Did you have a look at MassTransit before you went ahead with your message proxy? I am about to look into that to see if it supports that behaviour

Comment: @bayological We did look at MassTransit, but it was prior to this effort, and the decision had already been made to use NServiceBus.  We did not re-evaluate MassTransit over this need, so I can't advise you as to whether it supports the behavior we wanted.  Sorry.